# How to stop frozen user in lookup search window

Tags: lookup, user-record, lookup-filter

How to stop frozen user in lookup search window.

We have one requirement we need to stop displaying frozen user in lookup search layout .
any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do 2 things

1) Mark that user in active  or
2) Add lookup filter that restrict user from selecting frozen user

Comment: I want to filter out the only frozen user, an inactive user by default won't populate in look up search window .

When we make a user frozen, isFrozen field of UserLogin  become true. this field is not accessible in confriguration